# i18next goes back to default language with f5

Tags: typescript, translation, i18next, react-i18next, i18next-browser-languagedetector

*i18n.js*

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import enTranslation from '../locales/en.json';
import trTranslation from '../locales/tr.json';
import deTranslation from '../locales/de.json';
import I18nextBrowserLanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
const resources = {
    en: {
        translation:
            enTranslation
    },
    tr: {
        translation:
            trTranslation
    },
    de: {
        translation:
            deTranslation
    },

};


i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
    resources,
    debug: true,
    fallbackLng: 'de',
    interpolation: {
        escapeValue: false,
    },

}).catch(e => console.log(e))

export default i18n;
```

*_app.tsx*

```
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  
  return <>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
        <Header />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
        <Footer />
      </I18nextProvider>
      <Script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></Script>
    </Provider>
  </>
}
```

*LanguageSelect.tsx* -Component in my header

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

const LanguageSelection = () => {
    const { i18n } = useTranslation();

    const handleLanguageChange = (event: any) => {
        const selectedLanguage = event.target.value;
        i18n.changeLanguage(selectedLanguage);
    };

    return (

        <div style={{ zIndex: 99 }}>
            <select className='text-sm' defaultValue={i18n.language} id="language" onChange={handleLanguageChange}>
                <option value="en">EN</option>
                <option value="tr">TR</option>
                <option value="de">DE</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    );
};

export default LanguageSelection;
```

When I start the project it comes with DE language, then I switch it to TR or EN it works fine untill I refresh page, after refresh it goes back to DE. I want to keep it on last selection, couldn't achieve it.

I tried many ways that I found on the internet but nothing changed.

Tried remove fallbackLng -> gives hydrogen errors

Tried fallbackLng: localStorage.getItem('i18nextLng') || 'de' -> this gives me localStorage is not defined error

Tried lng:'de'

Tried to set languageDetector but couldn't make it work either...

I want to keep last selection of language, maybe from user's browser language (this would be perfect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it by hand.

For instance:

- on language change - save the language to Local Storage
- on app load - get language from Local Storage and set it to i18n